# how to custom route in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to create a custom route that routes like this

when the client request `http://server/logout`
it will be directed to to AccountController controller and to LogOff method

How to do this in ASP.MVC 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could insert the following route definition **before** the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LogOut",
    url: "logout",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOff" }
);
```

Comment: wow thanks, it turns out I only needed to change the order of the routes >_< sorry